# Android style lookup in library project

Tags: android-layout, android

I am having the hardest time trying to get this to work. I have a custom control that I have moved into a library project which is referenced from my main app project. In the library project, I have a few styleable attrs defined (ignore the typo in the last one, fixing :-)):

```
<declare-styleable name="PinLockKeyPad">
    <attr name="keypadKeyBackground" format="reference" />
    <attr name="cancelKeyBackground" format="reference" />
    <attr name="keypadButtonTextSize" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="cancelButtonTextSize" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="backspaceButtonImageResouce" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

These styleable attrs are not referenced in java code anywhere but are used in the library's styles.xml file like so:

```
<style name="KeypadButton" parent="MatchBoth">
    <item name="android:background">?keypadKeyBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">?keypadButtonTextSize</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
</style>
```

In my main app I have done the following in styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar.ForceOverflow">
    <item name="keypadKeyBackground">@drawable/keypad_key</item>
    <item name="cancelKeyBackground">@drawable/keypad_key</item>
    <item name="pinHintTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="pinInputBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="keypadButtonTextSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="cancelButtonTextSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="backspaceButtonImageResouce">@drawable/ic_delete</item>
</style>
```

And have set Theme.App to by my applications theme. However, I am getting crashes when trying to inflate the classes which reference the KeypadButton style due to these attrs not being defined. What am I missing?

Sidenote: this may be associated with having multiple libraries in my main app. I have another app which does this EXACT same thing and does not crash, but it only uses one library (the one where these styles are used).

Comment: Are you using same package name for all library project? try giving every library project a unique package name in their AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Yeah, they all have different package names already :-(. Thanks though!

Comment: I can work around this by defining a default style in the library's styles file and then setting it before inflation in the custom view.

context.getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.DefaultPinLockKeyPad, false);

but, this is obviously a hack